# German Tank Problem - Expectation and Variance of Maximum Order Statistic

Tags: expected-value, variance, order-statistics

I have been looking through the German Tank Problem recently, There are many videos and references regarding this problem but what got me thinking is that I know that at first, the Maximum Likelihood Estimator is equal to the maximum of the sample.

I also understand that this comes from a Uniform Discrete Distribution without replacement. I have been trying to find resources to help me with finding the Expectation and the Variance of the estimator  X<sub>(m)</sub>  where   X<sub>(m)</sub> is the maximum of the sample.

I have been looking up order statistics regarding the discrete uniform distribution without replacement but couldn't find anything related. Would really appreciate some guidance or links that I can look up on the Expectation and the Variance of this estimator.

Comment: A [didactic link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.08162.pdf) among many others as you say...